# How to teach modeling physical systems?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, education, models

While working as a teaching assistant for introductory experimental physics classes (newtonian mechanics and electromagnetism) for the last couple of years, I faced a certain kind of issue again and again. Of course the course material is hard and some students cope better with it than others. But almost all attendants are struggling with analyzing a given real life problem and modeling it with the tools from the lecture.

Once the formulas are written down, most of them have very little problem arriving at the correct solution, even if it involves some difficult integrals or long calculations. The most extreme case of this was a math student who took the class for her minor. I learned some things about math through discussions with her, and the equations posed no challenge at all. But she just could not graph the forces acting on a rotating point mass correctly or add them together in the right way once they were drawn on the blackboard.

This problem is amplified in exams, where errors creep in because of stress and time. But most students don't even get to the point where they can start calculating things, because the basic premise is often wrong. And because of this they lose a lot of points, as they can't make much progress from a wrong start.

Because we separate the exam into three parts and one of these focuses on "understanding" (very simple one line calculations, the goal is to reason correctly about the physical system and predict its behaviour), we actually have some data on that. In general, this part has by far the lowest mean score while the calculation heavy part fares much better. Also compared to past exams, it seems to have been getting worse, because six or seven years ago this part had a higher mean score.

I am certain, that I had the same problems in the beginning and just learned these things over time through practicing with many examples. But in what way can a teaching instructor or professor teach students to model real life physical systems?

Remark: I chose this site over "Mathematics Educators", because it is strictly about teaching modeling in a physical sense, so I think it fits better here. Also I am not sure, if the "models" tag is appropiate here.

Also if you think this might have something to do with the education system, I am talking about first year bachelor degree courses for physics majors and minors at a German university.

Edit: I will give some examples from memory to clarify the issue.

Example 1 (from the third week): Consider a chairoplane with a given height, rope length and mass of the person inside it. The whole system rotates at a constant angular velocity. Task: model the situation appropriately and draw the acting forces. Problems: a tangential force is drawn, so the person would constantly accelerate in the direction of movement and no force along the rope is considered.

Example 2 (from the 4th week): a ball sits on a table, that stands on the ground, and everything is at rest. Task: draw all forces in the schematic and in the abstraction (that just consists of blocks for ball, ground and table). Problems: no force between the table and the ground is included and forces are not transferred correctly to the abstraction

Example 3(from an exam): a metal rod is lying on a metal loop and there is a current running through everything. The whole system is inside a homogeneous magnetic field and tilted 30 degrees. Task: consider all forces acting on the system and describe its motion. Problems: Lenz's law is not identified to work here; even if it is identified, some ignore it when describing the motion afterwards (so it is described as a rolling motion with the acceleration given by earth's gravity and the slope of the system).

Comment: Could you give an example or two of what the students may be struggling with? It is in the category of conceptual questions, I can see, where the student must learn to "think physics".

Comment: @Steeven Yes, we start with distance/time-diagrams and then move towards forces acting on point masses. The problems really start once we talk about pistons sliding on a surface and rotating systems.

Comment: Is it that the students are presented with a real-world problem and struggle to make the connection to theory? For example (over-simplified), they struggle to connect, "A car starts from rest and reaches a speed of 60 km/h in 15 s. Calculate the acceleration."?

Comment: @Mick Yes, I think that is the key issue here. They have problems relating the real, physical phenomena to a mathematical construct they can work with. Once this is established, they can usually move forward. A side effect of this is, that they have an easier time in theoretical physics, because modeling the situation mathematically is often not required.

Comment: I would suggest you to always require of them to make a sketch, a drawing. Every single time. For every single question they ever encounter. Regardless of how simple. Draw it and look at that drawing, and they will with much more confidence see anything missing or misunderstood.

Comment: @Steeven We already do that, we discuss them extensively in class. I also brought this issue to the other (older) TAs and their response was 'they don't learn anything in school, nothing we can do about it'. I don't feel qualified to say something about the education system, but feel, that we just can't throw our hands up in the air. If the prerequisites changed, we need to adapt to them.

Comment: My professional career centered around math modeling of physics systems.  The first requirement is that the students have a firm understanding of the physical fundaments.  Secondly, for a given problem, they need to be able to articulate (in words) the physical mechanisms involved.  The ability to do this all-important step evolves from practice in solving many many problems.  Thirdly, they need to be taught good modeling practices, such as always using free body diagrams.

Comment: Although there is a tag for education, the answers to this question will be primarily based on opinion (personal experience as a teacher or learner) rather than the results of scientific educational research. There is probably no single definitive answer. The underlying issues about how we think and learn are probably better addressed through psychology than physics. So I think the question might be *off topic* here.

Comment: I framed the question in this general way to prevent opinioated answers, because there should be general techniques and approaches to teaching modeling, shouldn't it? Maybe there is no single technique, but a collection that proved effective (hopefully even through education research) is all I ask for. If there has not been any such research, I wonder why, because this is a very fundamental issue. A huge part of physics is modeling of the systems we measure.

Comment: I have roughly six years experience teaching intro courses, and I would agree with @Chester that being able to express their thinking verbally is a mark of students who will do well. But I don't have any really good suggestions for how to *teach* the skills. I use some group problem solving ala Heller to get the students to talk to each other,  plus scaffolded sequences of related exercises, and as much personal attention as I can afford. And then I just kinds hope the students muddle through. Overall results on learning gains are only modestly better than "sage on a stage".

Comment: *"because there should be general techniques and approaches to teaching modeling, shouldn't it?"* The wide variety of techniques suggested under the moniker *Physics Education Research*, and the variation in results both between instructors using the "same" technique and between different techniques in the hands of individual instructors suggests that it may not be that simple.

Comment: Afaik, pedagogical questions are generally considered off-topic due to being broad and/or primarily opinion based.

Comment: A [meta discussion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10682/44126) taking this question as a starting point.

Comment: I remember not understanding things because it was not clear where the force came from and where it was acting, and what parameters it depended on, and with respect to which reference frame and orientation angles were, and between what things the angles were, et cetera. In example 3, is the whole universe tilted 30 degrees, or the magnetic field, or the things inside the magnetic field, etc....

Comment: Ex 1 (circular motion requires tangential force) is a misconception - you cannot address this by teaching modelling technique. Ex 2 could be mis-communication / custom :  contact forces between table and floor are ignored because the student assumes the question is asking about the interaction between ball and table, as in classroom problems he/she has encountered. In Ex 3 there are gravitational as well as magnetic forces. If the students are taught topics of physics separately, it is not surprising that they assume the problem is either gravity or electromagnetism but not both.

Comment: Identifying what is relevant in a problem requires insight, which is a product of experience and knowledge. It is a skill which cannot be obtained by rote learning of a modelling technique. Students in all subjects learn and improve by watching an expert and getting feedback on their own performance.

Answer (score -1):

This is a challenge faced by physics (and other) teachers the world over. There are various pedagogical approaches and students respond differently depending on their preferred/dominant learning styles.

One approach is to:

- sketch out the problem (draw a picture). From the example in my earlier comment ("A car starts from rest and reaches a speed of 60 km/h in 15 s. Calculate the acceleration."), it can be as simple as a rectangle with circles - a box with wheels - and some labels, arrows, etc. to help visualise the problem.
- identify the variables:

  - initial speed (0 km/h)
  - final speed (60 km/h)
  - time 15 s
- convert non-SI units to SI units
- identify the relevant formula

I think from this point your students are ok with the calculation side, it is identifying which equation is needed from the description.